# Is it possible to open About Ubuntu window in Xubuntu?

Tags: command-line, unity, xubuntu, settings

I've been using Ubuntu for ages (Karmic or Lucid, I don't remember) and if my memory serves me well, the **Details** or **Overview** section was present in the system settings in **GNOME 2** and **Unity**. But when I switched to Xubuntu years ago, that section was nowhere to be found in the settings.

Is it possible to install it? Or is it installed but not visible? Can I run it from the CLI? I've tried typing `details` and `about`but these are not present or don't exist. If I type `overview` bash suggests me a very different command that is used to manage audio.[image: Ubuntu Unity Details section screenshot]

Comment: I would refer to that as the *About* page, and it's specific to the desktop being used. Every desktop has it, but it looks different if using Unity, GNOME, Xfce, LXQt, MATE, KDE Plasma, etc...  The program (thus command) also varies on the desktop you're asking about; as my system is a multi-desktop install; I have multiple installed (one for each desktop, ie. one for Xfce, LXQt, MATE, GNOME... and the command used controls which opens)

Comment: fyi:  `xfce4-about` is the Xfce ABOUT app & thus command used to display the ABOUT details when using Xfce/Xubuntu. I'd use `lxqt-about` to view the LXQt ABOUT app & details which apply to the desktop I'm currently logged in with & using....   You can use whatever ABOUT apps you have installed, but a Xubuntu install comes with `xfce4-about` only by default as it's using the libraries/toolkits & details of the Xfce session that is running on a Xubuntu install.

Answer (score 2):

I would refer to that as the About page, and it's specific to the desktop being used. Every desktop has it, but it looks different if using Unity, GNOME, Xfce, LXQt, MATE, KDE Plasma, etc...

The program (*thus command*) also varies on the desktop you're asking about; as my system is a multi-desktop install; I have multiple installed (one for each desktop, ie. one for Xfce, LXQt, MATE, GNOME... and the command used controls which opens)

`xfce4-about` is the Xfce ABOUT app & thus command used to display the ABOUT details when using Xfce/Xubuntu.

I'd use `lxqt-about` to view the LXQt ABOUT app & details which apply to the desktop I'm currently logged in with & using. (I logged in with a Lubuntu session today, thus am using LXQt currently)

You can use whatever ABOUT apps you have installed, but a Xubuntu install comes with `xfce4-about` only by default as it's using the libraries/toolkits & details of the Xfce session that is running on a Xubuntu install.

You didn't provide an actual release you're asking about (*and the focal page you showed was from early 2020 or late 2019 prior to 20.04 being released*), but to view the GNOME details you use

`gnome-control-center about`

BUT that will require it to be installed; which it is not on a *default* Xubuntu system  (*it is on my own bloated system as I have four desktops installed*)

Comment: Do note;  I tested the `gnome-control-center about` on two systems (*different releases*), it worked perfectly on one, but on the other release it opened `gnome-control-center` but it didn't open on the ABOUT page.   It may or may not work on your release; but as you didn't provide a release...  so it may or may not work exactly as outlined for your *unstated* release.   (*It maybe the `gnome-control-center` is just opening at the last page selected & thus the 'about' was doing nothing; sorry I'm not a GNOME user normally so don't explore it that much*)

Comment: FWIW for KDE / KUbuntu: `kinfocenter` will do the trick....

Comment: Yep can confirm `kinfocenter` .... (*though it really just shows how BLOATED my boxes are given it was already installed!*)  ... `mate-about` will show MATE's About screen etc; though some desktop ABOUT screens show less system detail than others...

Comment: Sorry avout that. It's 22.04.

I guess mine was an ignorant question, but being Xubuntu an official Ubuntu flavor and being XFCE a fork of GNOME2 I thought Canonical ported that About page on other flavors apart from the original GNOME2 and Unity. It seems I was wrong.

Comment: I knew about the XFCE4 About dialog box, but I just like how the main Ubuntu dialog box shows the info and the detail it shows. Thanks again.

Comment: Xfce was **not** a fork of GNOME2, Xfe existed well before GNOME existed as it's an older desktop; GNOME was created as CDE or the Common Desktop was owned by companies which led to KDE (using Qt libs/toolkits) which the FSF didn't like leading to the creation of GNOME...  Xfe had pieces of CDE incorporated in it before this having become Xfce, but this predates the KDE or GNOME creation by some time....  (The XF relates to Xforms.. which predates the KDE/Qt/GNOME/GTK saga by a number of years... being something found in CDE or the earlier X windows)

Comment: Early versions of Xfce didn't use GTK, as that didn't yet exist.. Xfce was *ported* so as to use GTK once it existed, as the prior toolkits/libraries it used where no longer supported.. Xfce is an older desktop if compared to younger GNOME or KDE.    *This detail I've added is real old & from memory an likely not well written... I have a series of books (1991-1992) on the X Window System that give great detail on some of this; alas not GNOME or later creations though as they didn't then exist. Those books aren't talking about Xfce either, but the language & tools show clearly why Xfce formed*